# Curl graphql query to insert with html character

Tags: curl, graphql, shopify-api

I need insert in Shopify from CURL with graphql a html traslation but not accept "<" character I try with \< \< but nothing..

`{\"query\": \"mutation CreateTranslation($id: ID!, $translations: [TranslationInput!]!) { translationsRegister(resourceId: $id, translations: $translations) { userErrors {message field} translations {key value locale} } }\",\"variables\": {\"id\": \"gid://shopify/Product/myid\",\"translations\": [{\"key\": \"body_html\",\"value\": \"<p>La Camicia da Uomo in Cotone con Colletto Francese in Blu Chiaro, tailor fit.  Questa camicia è più di un semplice capo d'abbigliamento; è una dichiarazione di gusto raffinato, progettata per elevare il tuo stile in una varietà di occasioni.</p><ul>....</li></ul>\",\"locale\": \"it\",\"translatableContentDigest\": \"73f987270db7311a720b001d6155d8f008db796b7341d1c59177a6c02ab129c2\"}]}}`

if I remove "<" and ">" is all ok but I lost the html code..

tnx

Answer (score 0):

from linux is ok, is only in dos "mode" that not accept <

```
curl --location 'https://mysite.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-04/graphql.json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'X-Shopify-Access-Token: mycode' \
--data '{
  "query": "mutation CreateTranslation($id: ID!, $translations: [TranslationInput!]!) { translationsRegister(resourceId: $id, translations: $translations) { userErrors {message field} translations {key value locale} } }",
  "variables": {
    "id": "gid://shopify/Product/8314445857032",
    "translations": [{
      "key": "body_html",
      "value": "<p>La Camicia da Uomo in Cotone con Colletto Francese in Blu Chiaro, tailor fit. Questa camicia è più di un semplice capo d'\''abbigliamento; è una dichiarazione di gusto raffinato, progettata per elevare il tuo stile in una varietà di occasioni.</p><ul>.</li></ul>",
      "locale": "it",
      "translatableContentDigest": "73f987270db7311a720b001d6155d8f008db796b7341d1c59177a6c02ab129c2"
    }]
  }
}'
```